# Why does Thymeleaf generate a wrong id?

Tags: thymeleaf

I created a form using Thymeleaf. This form contains a textfield and a label for it. But Thymeleaf does not assign the correct id to the `for` attribute of the label (or in fact it assigns the wrong id to the textfield).

This is the template:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/test}" th:object="${nameBean}" method="post">
<div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? has-error">
    <label class="control-label" th:for="${#ids.next('name')}">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" th:field="*{name}" />
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

And this is the generated HTML:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" id="name" name="name" value="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

The `for` attribute should be correct according to the Thymeleaf guide, but the id of the textfield should have a number appended. Why is this number not appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you only need this for iterations. Normally you can simply use  `for='name'`. If you use seq, I would assume that `th:id=#ids.seq('name')` at the input-element would be the right way.